# how to restrict website based ip address in joomla site?

Tags: joomla, ip-address

how to restrict website based ip address in joomla site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .htaccess

```
#require authentication of requests
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
AuthType basic
Require valid-user
#deny access to all, allow for selected ip's / domains
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 123.123.123.123 googlebot.com google.com google-analytics.com
#if any of these rules are satisfied they may proceed
Satisfy Any
```

You'll need to add a password file.